# PowerApp unable to get all Users states

Tags: office365api, powerapps

I'm try to get all user state from office365User

```
Office365Users.UserProfileV2(Office365Users.MyProfile().Id).state
```

However, it's not a solution because it will retrieve my information only. 
as I would like to get all stats of our 365 users on combo box.

thanks for your help in advanced

Answer (score 1):

You might struggle to do it all in a combo box, you can do it in a gallery thought.

There is no list users, so to get all the users you have to use the searchUser function if your search string is blank it returns all the users.

```
Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm: TextSearchBox1.Text})
```

**Gallery**

Items set to

```
Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm: TextSearchBox1.Text})
```

Then a label within the card set the text to

```
Office365Users.UserProfileV2(ThisItem.UserPrincipalName).state
```

**Combo Box**

To get the state I had to place a label next the combo box, I was unable to get it work from the

Items set to

```
Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm: TextSearchBox1.Text})
```

then set the label text set to

```
Office365Users.UserProfileV2(ComboBox1.SelectedItems.UserPrincipalName).state
```

Useful links

[Connect to Office 365 Users connection from PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users)

[Office 365 Users Connection Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/)